# BigQuery ML tutorial - "Failure in computing PREDICT: Null value found in input."

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm following the BQML [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigqueryml-natality) on how to predict the birth weight of a child based on the baby’s gender, the length of the pregnancy, and demographic information about the mother.

When the SQL for evaluation of the model is executed, BigQuery chucks the following error:

```
Failure in computing PREDICT: Null value found in input.
```

This is the evaluation SQL:

```
 #standardSQL
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ML.EVALUATE(MODEL `bqml_tutorial.natality_model`,
    (
    SELECT
      weight_pounds,
      is_male,
      gestation_weeks,
      mother_age,
      CAST(mother_race AS STRING) AS mother_race
    FROM
      `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality`
    WHERE
      weight_pounds IS NOT NULL))
```

[image]

The SQL used for creating the model was:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE MODEL `bqml_tutorial.natality_model`
OPTIONS
  (model_type='linear_reg',
    input_label_cols=['weight_pounds']) AS
SELECT
  weight_pounds,
  is_male,
  gestation_weeks,
  mother_age,
  CAST(mother_race AS string) AS mother_race
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality`
WHERE
  weight_pounds IS NOT NULL
  AND RAND() < 0.001
```

Funnily enough, when predicting, it works just fine. The problem is always when trying to evaluate the model.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help understand the issue you can run below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  COUNTIF(weight_pounds IS NULL) weight_pounds_nulls,
  COUNTIF(is_male IS NULL) is_male_nulls,
  COUNTIF(gestation_weeks IS NULL) gestation_weeks_nulls,
  COUNTIF(mother_age IS NULL) mother_age_nulls,
  COUNTIF(mother_race IS NULL) mother_race_nulls
FROM (
  SELECT
    weight_pounds,
    is_male,
    gestation_weeks,
    mother_age,
    CAST(mother_race AS STRING) AS mother_race
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality`
  WHERE weight_pounds IS NOT NULL
)
```

with result as

```
Row weight_pounds_nulls is_male_nulls   gestation_weeks_nulls   mother_age_nulls    mother_race_nulls    
1   0                   0               4749775                 0                   9874846
```

So, run below instead for EVALUATION

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ML.EVALUATE(MODEL `bqml_tutorial.natality_model`,
    (
      SELECT
        weight_pounds,
        is_male,
        gestation_weeks,
        mother_age,
        CAST(mother_race AS STRING) AS mother_race
      FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality`
      WHERE weight_pounds IS NOT NULL
      AND gestation_weeks IS NOT NULL
      AND mother_race IS NOT NULL
     ))
```

so it will produce below evaluation

```
Row mean_absolute_error mean_squared_error  mean_squared_log_error  median_absolute_error   r2_score                explained_variance   
1   0.957266870271064   1.6762698039982795  0.03411192361406951     0.73998132611964        0.047271288906207354    0.04732780918772106
```

And you should do same adjustment for PREDICT, I think

Answer (score 0):

BQML currently auto fills those NULLs for you. Please try again with the original data (without non-null filter).

Comment: is this recent improvement?

Comment: Yes, the feature has been re-enabled recently.